# how to open jquery ui modal tab window after successful event

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-dialog

link on a page opens ui modal window say A

ui modal window A has two tabs (using ui modal tabs) i.e.

```
<div id="master_tab_div">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab_header">Header info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_detail">Details</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now on #tab_detail there is an import link that inserts data (and should show on #tab_detail).

When I click the data insertion link I want it to be able to show the refreshed #tab_detail tab with the insertion/refreshed data.

I can't seem to figure out how to open the said tab again after the insertion process. I can only direct to the main page and from there I have to click twice to reach the #tab_detail. Is there anyway I can avoid this and open up the #tab_detail directly, once data insertion is successful?

Comment: `$('a[href="#tab_detail"]').trigger('click');`

Comment: I want an auto redirect to #tab_detail. Also this did not work, perhaps I missed out something on explanation. The link on #tab_detail for data insertion is sending control to a 'process.php' page, and I want auto redirection to $tab_detail if there are no errors in the insertion process. I have also tried $('#master_tab_div').tabs('select',1); - didn't work either. Javascript history.back also taking me back to the main page.